# How can check ipv4 address in shell. Like is it *.*.1.* or *.*.0.*?

Tags: shell, wifi, ipv4

So here I tried to get from the ifconfig file, but same with errors with simple ifconfig command

```
!#/bin/sh
if [/home/pi/ifconfig | grep -Eo ‘inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*’ | grep -Eo ‘([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*’ | grep -v ‘127.0.0.1’ = *.*.1.*]
then
echo “good1”
else
echo “notGood2”
fi
```

The errors what I got

```
test: 2: test: [/home/pi/ifconfig: not found
grep: =: No such file or directory
grep: *.*.1.*]: No such file or directory
notGood2
```

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is a good resource to check for syntax errors in your shell code. Hint `[` is a **command** not just syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ip addr` to show the IP addresses of all interfaces and subnets on your host:

```
$ ip -f inet addr show | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }'
127.0.0.1/8
192.168.0.2/24
```

If you don't care about the subnet, you can strip that out:

```
$ ip -f inet addr show | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }' | cut -d/ -f1
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.2
```

Per comment, if you want to see for some reason only what the third octet of your IP address(es) is/are, this is simple enough:

```
# given this:
$ ip -f inet addr show | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }'
127.0.0.1/8
192.168.25.2/24
# we can do this:
$ ip -f inet addr show | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }' | cut -d. -f3
0
25
```

Comment: O can use this like normal command, but how can I use it in shell? My main problem that, I cant check the IPv4 address what number contains on the third position (in shell).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(/sbin/ifconfig | grep inet | awk '{print $2}')
do
    if [[ $i  =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.1|0.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
    echo "$i good1"
    else 
    echo "$i notGood2" 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer guys
I will explain the i = 1 because it is

```
i=1
if [ $i = 1 ]; then
echo $i good1
else
echo $i notGood2
fi
```

This is what I want
Anyway both of you helped to get the right answer guys! Thx